# i can send UDP packets from my pc to another pc but I am unable to send tcp packets

Tags: python

I am running this code to send unicast packet but i am getting connectionrefuse error(error-111)

```
import socket
from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL 
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL) 


TCP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
TCP_PORT = 23
MESSAGE = "HELLO, I AM PC"

print("TCP TARGET IP : ", TCP_IP)
print("TCP TARGET PORT :", TCP_PORT)
print("MESSAGE:", MESSAGE)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.sendto(bytes(MESSAGE, encoding= "utf-8"), (TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
```

but while i am sending UDP packets by using below code, i can do it-

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "10.4.0.136"
UDP_PORT = 443
MESSAGE = "HELLO, I AM DESIGN-8"

print("UDP TARGET IP : ", UDP_IP)
print("UDP TARGET PORT :", UDP_PORT)
print("MESSAGE:", MESSAGE)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.sendto(bytes(MESSAGE, encoding= "utf-8"), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
```

Comment: How are you telling the method `sendto` that it is a TCP packet?

Comment: There should be a listener on port 23 to accept the connection. If on linux, do `nc -l 23`. You need to use `sudo` for a port number < 1024